# Value of optional type 'UIWindow?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'viewWithTag' of wrapped base type 'UIWindow'

Tags: ios, swift, uiwindow

I have converted an Objective-C file to Swift and it is now converted as:

```
if isCaptured {
    let colourView = UIView(frame: window.frame)
    colourView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    colourView?.tag = 1234
    colourView?.alpha = 0

    window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
    window.addSubview(colourView)

    // fade in the view
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        colourView?.alpha = 1
    })
} else {
    // grab a reference to our coloured view
    let colourView = window.viewWithTag(1234)

    // fade away colour view from main view
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        colourView?.alpha = 0
    }) { finished in
        // remove when finished fading
        colourView?.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

But I am getting an error of:

> Value of optional type 'UIWindow?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'viewWithTag' of wrapped base type 'UIWindow'

The screenshot is attached hereby:

[image: error screenshot]

How to rectify this?

Answer (score 1):

You already have unwrapped it with `window!.makeKeyAndVisible()`.
So, you can just do the same here -> `window!.viewWithTag(1234)`.

Would also suggest to read https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html. You need to get the base ideas to know what force unwrapping means and when it's safe to use.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is with the window then you need to get that from `UIApplication` also, You need to unwrap your window variable, either use `if-let` or `guard-let` or force unwrap before doing `viewWithTag()`.

```
if let delegate = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate), let window = delegate.window {
        if let view123 = window.viewWithTag(123) {

        }
    }
```

Comment: as that window has been unwrapped in that `if`, you can use that window variable anywhere inside that `if` as in that `if-statement` window is not `nil`